# How to call a function in a singleton class, using reflection in c#

Tags: c#

I try to call a function in a singleton class by reflection. I get following Exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.

Class and calling method are placed below. Anyone an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class SetStatus{
     private static readonly SetStatus instance = new SetStatus();
     protected SortedDictionary<int, string> resources = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();

    public static SetStatus Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
    protected override void LoadResources()
    {
        resources.Add(0, MyApp.Resources.Localization.Approved);
        resources.Add(1, MyApp.Resources.Localization.Rejected);
        resources.Add(2, MyApp.Resources.Localization.Revoked);
    }

    public SetStatus()
    {
        LoadResources();
    }

    public SortedDictionary<int, string> Resources
    {
        get
        {
            return resources;
        }
    }
}



void ResetStaticEnums()
{
    string methodName = "LoadResources";
    MethodInfo method = typeof(SetStatus).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
    method.Invoke(SetStatus.Instance, Type.EmptyTypes);
}
```

Comment: 3 calls to `resources.Add(...` has the same value as key.. And you can not have duplicate keys in dictionary. That's why you have this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `LoadResources` twice.

1. In your constructor `public SetStatus()` with `private static readonly SetStatus instance = new SetStatus();`
2. In your call `method.Invoke(SetStatus.Instance, Type.EmptyTypes);`

And this results in the exception:

> An entry with the same key already exists

Remove `LoadResources();` in your constructor and it will work (one time)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add the same key to a Dictionary multiple times

```
   protected override void LoadResources()
    {
        resources.Add(Convert.ToInt32(WeekStatus.AdministrationApproved), MyApp.Resources.Localization.Approved);
        resources.Add(Convert.ToInt32(WeekStatus.AdministrationApproved), MyApp.Resources.Localization.Rejected);
        resources.Add(Convert.ToInt32(WeekStatus.AdministrationApproved), MyApp.Resources.Localization.Revoked);
    }
```

You are adding AdministrationApproved 3 times.

Comment: Sorry I tried to simplify my example and copy/paste a bit too much. I don't have the same keys for my sorted dictionary.